# Are background iOS apps that use the *standard* location services restarted on device reboot?

Tags: ios, background, geolocation, launch

I have an iPhone app that uses the standard location (as opposed to the significant change) services. I'm aware of the issues with battery, etc, but we need the continuous accuracy.

It generally working fine. We've set the location background mode in the plist file, etc.

However, the app doesn't seem to be relaunched when the device is rebooted.

Searching around, I've seen the odd comment that suggest that while apps that register for *significant updates* will be relaunched on a reboot (when an update is received), apps using the *standard* location services might not be.

However, I can't find any Apple documentation that clearly states this (or even a clear, current, third-party statement). Does anyone have the definitive answer on this?

If *standard* location updates don't relaunched the app after a reboot, is there a workaround - e.g. using signification updates to bootstrap the standard updates? Does anyone have an example?

I've seen people suggesting that you can register for VoIP, but I don't want to do that, as it doesn't use those services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps that register for significant location updates *do not* get relaunched on system reboot. They *do*, however, get restarted if a new location update comes through and the system has terminated them previously. What this effectively means is that if you app is backgrounded and terminated by the system (to conserve memory, etc) it will be relaunched in the background.

To quote from Apple's docs:

This is *different* from the `UIBackgroundMode` VOIP key, which *does* cause the app to be relaunched after a system restart.

This is documented in Apple's App Programming Guide, under the 'Background Execution' section ([link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)). It is a rather verbose document, so here are the two bits you want:

> Including the voip value in the UIBackgroundModes key lets the system know that it should allow the app to run in the background as needed to manage its network sockets. An app with this key is also relaunched in the background immediately after system boot to ensure that the VoIP services are always available.

And for location:

> [The UIBackgroundMode location key] does not preclude the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver

Comment: So the app is also restarted when using *standard* location services - as opposed to *significant location* services, when a new location update arrives?

Comment: It can do, but only if you explicitly provide the correct `UIBackgroundMode` key. This is to allow apps that require fine-grain positioning (navigation apps, primarily) to run in the background successfully.